# Interpreting book quote about (plausible) deductions

Tags: logic

In a book I am reading there is this quote:

> ```
> if A is true, then B is true
> B is true
> -------------------------------
> therefore, A becomes more plausible. (*)
> ```
>
> The evidence does not prove that A is true, but verification of one of
> its consequences does give us more confidence in A

I understand this. Then it proceeds

> For example, let
>
> A ≡ it will start to rain by 10 am at the latest;
>
> B ≡ the sky will become cloudy before 10 am
>
> Observing clouds at 9:45 am does not give us a logical certainty that
> the rain will follow; nevertheless our common sense, obeying the weak
> syllogism, may induce us to change our plans and behave as if we
> believed that it will, if those clouds are sufficiently dark

This line I am also following. Because this I think is basically concrete example of above. i.e. same as basically the line marked with * above. Isn't it?

But confusion comes afterwards. Then it says:

> This example shows also that the major premise, ‘if A then B’
> expresses B only as a logical consequence of A; and not necessarily a
> causal physical consequence, which could be effective only at a later
> time. The rain at 10 am is not the physical cause of the clouds at
> 9:45 am. Nevertheless, the proper logical connection is not in the
> uncertain causal direction (clouds =⇒ rain), but rather (rain =⇒
> clouds), which is certain, although noncausal.

Honestly I can't even cite one sentence in this paragraph which I don't understand because in a way the whole paragraph is unclear to me what the author is trying to say.
Can someone if he/she understands it rephrase it in a different way?

For example, more specifically, what does the author mean with:

- This example shows also that the major premise, ‘if A then B’ expresses B only as a
  logical consequence of A; and not necessarily a causal physical consequence?
- Actually I think rain in real world doesn't necessarily mean sky will become cloudy in the real world AFAIK. In that case, was this even valid example for a relation *if A then B*?

Comment: See [Indicative Conditionals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/conditionals/) and [The Logic of Conditionals](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-conditionals/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, we may have clouds and no rain, but we cannot have rain without clouds.

This means that the state of affair "rain with no clouds" is impossible, that in turn reads:

> "if rain, then clouds" (aka: clouds are *necessary* for rain),

and this fits with the definition of [Logical consequence](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-consequence). which does not mean "cause-effect relation".